# Changing variable name in Python

Tags: python

I want to do the following in Python:

```
for i in range (1,2):
    string = 2
    string="string"+str(i)   
print string1
print string2
```

I'm expecting the output string1=2 and string2=2 but getting the following error.

```
NameError: name 'string1' is not defined.
```

I want to store the value of string in new variable like string1 and string2 as defined above but I'm receiving the above error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No dynamic names are not supported by Python. I think you need array here?

Comment: Your're assigning the string `"string1"` to a variable named `string`. That's all that is going on here.  Note that `range(1,2)` is also just `[1]`. You're making up constructs in the language that don't exist, and asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain in plain English why you are trying to do this? You will probably be better off using an array or dictionary to store your strings, rather than dynamically named variables.

Comment: You should really start with the python tutorial. It will save you a lot of time... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic mistake here. First of all, dont use dynamic names as variable, they are reserved by Python.(eg. string,print)

Also you trying to print string1 and string2, there is no variable calling like them. You have a variable in *for* loop called *string* equal to *2*. After than you redefine it to equal to *string+str(i)* thats it. You can print **only *string* variable**. Because there is no more variable here.

```
string=2
string=string+"1"
```

This doesnt mean *string1* this means there is a variable called *string* and its equal to *string+"1"*.

> Also *for i in range(1,2)* will only *1*. 2 is not included. If you want *2*, you should write it (1,3).

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly.** When you do `print string1`, python tries to find variable `string1`, but you didn't define this variable before. To define variable in Python you need write something like this:

```
string1 = <some value or expression>
```

Also there are another ways to define variables, but they are outside of our problem.

**Secondly.** When you define a variable inside of a loop, the variable is available inside of this loop only (local variable) and will be destroyed after loop executing. Therefore, if you create a variable inside of your for-loop, you could not call the variable outside of the loop.

**Nevertheless.** To make your idea valid, you could use exec-statement:

```
i = 1
exec "string" + str(i) + " = " + str(i)

i = 2
exec "string" + str(i) + " = " + str(i)

print string1
print string2
```

The result of exec-statement will be understood by Python interpreter as a typical python line and will be executed. Actually, exec-statements are dangerous and can be sources of many mistakes and vulnerabilities. I would not recommend you use that too often.